# How do i use invisible walls properly ? Only after the player is walking out the terrain edge for some it's triggering

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I created a new empty gameobject in the hierarchy.
Attached to it a Box Collider:

And changed this settings on the Box Collider:

I set it's center property to 0,0,0
And set the size to x = 500 y = 600 z = 500
I also set the IsTrigger to be on( the checkbox is checked ).

And this is the Terrian details:

Width 500 Length 500 Height 600

When i'm looking at the scene window it seems like the box is around the terrain edges as it should be: ( Maybe in the right side there some space between the box and the terrain ? )

[Scene Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kOMVw.jpg)

This is the script attached to the empty gameobject ( InvisibleWalls ).

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class BoxCollider : MonoBehaviour {

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {

    }

    void OnTriggerExit(Collider c)
    {
        Destroy(c.gameObject);
    }
}
```

This is just for the test.
I added a break point on the line:

```
Destroy(c.gameObject);
```

Just to check when the event trigger.
The player ( ThirdPersonController ) is walking at speed 10.
When it's getting to the terrain edge the event is not triggering. The player keep walking on the air for some more seconds and only then the event is trigger and stop on the break point but then the player is already out the terrain area.

[Event Triggered](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TPF0f.jpg)

What i want to do is once the player is touching the wall trigger the event and do something for example keep the player walking on place so the wall is blocking him. But now the event is trigger when the player is out of the terrain area.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well this looks like the result of starting the player inside the collider, and using OnTriggerExit. That method won't be called until all of the player's collider is outside the defined box.

1. You could make the box smaller, so that there is some "padding" terrain around the outside of it. This is probably the quickest, but I would recommend option 2 instead.
2. You could make 4 box colliders, one for each wall. Instead of having one gigantic collider and waiting for the player to step out, think of these as skinny walls placed one to each side of your terrain. Don't make them triggers, and use the OnCollisionEnter event instead. This will automatically stop the player if you are moving him via physics, and you get the event as well. You can still make them triggers and use OnTriggerEnter if you want, but why not use the physics system since its there!

I hope this helps, good luck with your project!

Edit: [Found a video that explains method 2](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=flub8Ayc1iE)

Comment: How can i get the edges position of a terrain automatic ? I saw the video. The idea is great but if i want to build a wall exactly on each terrain side edge ? I mean for example build a 4 cubes automatic on each terrain edge with specific width and height but how do i get the terrain edges location/position and width ? Instead dragging the walls alone on my own.

Comment: That would require a little bit of scripting. You would need to get the terrains size and use that to place the colliders. (Center of terrain) +/- sizeOfTerrainInDirection/2. For example with a 500x500 terrain centered at (0,0,0), you would place a collider at (-250,0,0), (250,0,0),(0,0,250), and (0,0,-250).

Answer (score -1):

1) You Can call OnTriggerEnter if you want the player to be detected before it crosses the Trigger.

2) Another way will be To make the triggers Colliders and they will automatically block the player to cross the terrain boundary

Comment: A quick look at the picture shows that the player is always inside the trigger. OnTriggerEnter would be called at the start of the game and not called again unless the player exits and re-enters the play area.